# How to add Images according to database in Gallery

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am biginner in Android Development.
Here is the code for image adapter--
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;

private Integer[] mImageIds = {
         R.drawable.coupons
};

public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 
{
    mContext = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


// Override this method according to your need
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[index]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 400));

    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    return i;
}
```

}

now I want to take the image path from sqllite database and add it to Integer[] mImageIds.
i can retrieve the data from sqllite but don't know how to add it to mImageIds. so that i can show it to gallery.

Comment: First question: does your code work now? `I want to take the image path from sqllite database`. Please tell how such a path looks like. `add it to mImageIds`. That is inpossible. First, paths are no integers. Second you are loading images from drawables resource. You cannot use that for loading from a path. Please tell where the images would reside where the path points to?

Comment: Yes My Code Works! actully i dont want to add image path to mImageIds. suppose i have 25 entries into my database so i want to add R.drawable.coupons 25 times to mImageIds.

Comment: As you cannot add more elements to mImageIds array, once it has been defined, you could add them to an ArrayList<Integer> imageIds and then convert imageIds to mImageIds. Or throw away mImageIds and use directly the array list.

Comment: thnx for your help! but some code would be great, since i am beginner in android development.

Comment: So do away with mImagesIds. Then `ArrayList<Integer> imageIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. And adding in the loop use `imageIds.add(R.drawable.coupons);`. In getView use `imageIds.get(index)`.